# From the point of view of English language, when is the answer to a question "obvious", in general?

Tags: meaning, speech, language-formation

I am pondering over this question for a while. I was having a discussion with a friend and when she asked me a question, I responded to her that "Isn't it pretty obvious?" and she responded to me that the answer to the question wasn't obvious to her. Now, this is the definition of the word, obvious, according to [Cambridge online dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/obvious): easy to see, recognize, or understand.

So, in English, when is it okay to state or use the word "obvious"? When is the answer to a question obvious and when is it not?

Comment: *Obvious* is subjective. It's only certainly obvious to the person using the word. They might *assume* it's obvious to most other people, but they could be wrong about that.

Comment: An answer might be obvious if it is written right underneath a question, but even then some might not realise it is the answer, if they didn't understand the question. Someone knowing more facts than another might think something is obvious.

Comment: I don't think this question is really about English: It seems *obvious* that it is about the concept of obviousness, which can be expressed in a number of languages.